# Designing app for each screen size manually

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm not very good with Constraints, so basically, my idea is to place all the objects on the View Controller manually for every screen size (iPhone 4, 5, 6, iPad, etc).

Is it possible?

> Can I place all of them in one View Controller, or will I have to create a new View Controller for each screen size?

Comment: This is a ***terrible*** idea.

Comment: How can I change element properties considering the screen size? E.g. font size of a label? Without having to do it programmatically?

Comment: Given that in iOS 11 Apple have added a new "safe area" constraint, I would highly recommend learning auto-layout now. The addition of a "safe area" suggests to me that there will be upcoming iOS device designs that will not be regular rectangle shapes to design for, and could be any size.

Comment: Learn auto-layout. For instance, what happens in two months when Apple releases a third model iPhone and the screen size is something new? Or what would you have done last April when the latest iPad Pro 10.5 inch came out? The absolute *best* thing you can do? Get good with doing constraints. There are plenty of tutorials out there - you'll be glad you learned it a year from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible and you can do it in a single `ViewController` for each screen size. In `Interface Builder` if you open a `ViewController` or any other UI element, on the `Attributes Inspector` you can see small `+` signs next to most properties, using which you can add screen size specific properties. Using this approach you can manually create different sizings/font sizes/label texts, etc. for each screen size.

However, I would really recommend learning how to use `Autolayout`. It is one of the most powerful features of `iOS`s UI design and working on a large project with a complex UI you will pretty soon regret not learning how to use it. In the long-term it definitely saves you a lot of time and effort. With all the different screen sizes Apple has introduced in the past years, handling them manually is a real pain.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to use other values than "Compact" or "Regular"? E.g. is it possible to make different font sizes for iPhone 4 and 7?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned there are no further options than the ones you see there. Programatically you can check the exact screen size, but that's way too much effort again when you could so easily achieve the same effect using `Autolayout`. And if you use `Autolayout`, you don't have to do anything if Apple comes out with a new screen size in the future, it will be handled automatically in most cases.